# String matching a carriage return in Crystal Reports

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2010

I am wondering how to get the carriage return of a report field in Crystal Reports? I ask because when I use `split({tableField}, char(10))[1]`, I am not getting the first line of text.

For example, with the string

```
"Everyone
 Is Interested"
```

it should return the string "Everyone". Instead, it shows the original string, like the `split()` didn't do anything. The line break after "Everyone" (`char(10)`) does not seem to be matching the carriage return.

Comment: I don't get it. Can you show some more code or describe your problem a little bit more

Comment: Let me be clear with my prob. I want to know how many carriage return (chr(10)) are there in a table field (e.g, {Command.StudentName}) because I want to count the lines of row it could occupy on the crystal report. I have tried split({Command.TableField}, char(10)) to check how many carriage return or new line i could get. But I don't seem to get the right result. 

If i do it in the formula : StringVar sample : "Sample" + ChrW(10) +"Sample2", and used split(sample, chr(10)), I can get the right result. 

Please help me with this problem.

Answer (score 2):

You want `Split( {table.field}, Chr(10) )[1]`.

** edit **

```
// split the text on carriage returns
Local Stringvar Array lines := Split( {table.field}, Chr(10) );

// the number of carriage returns will be 1 less than the number of lines
Local Numbervar delimiters := Ubound(lines)-1;
```

Comment: Hi craig, I  want to get the number of rows a field can oocupy that's why I want to split it by chr(10) (carriage return). But using split({Command.TableField}, chr(10)) does not seem to solve my problem. I cannot get the number of carriage return a table field has.

Comment: I appreciate that @craig. But, the problem is that, there is no Chr(10) in the table.field itself. I would want to check the new line the crystal report automatically produces.


example:

if the table field has the value : "Everyone Is Interested",

then on the crystal report :

"Everyone
Is
Interested"

.. I would like to get the carriage return of the crystal report itself and not from the value of the table field.

Comment: "Everyone is Interested" on my example should occupy 3 rows. I should of course count the carriage return (new line) the field has. It seems that there is no way to count the carriage return when the field is word wrapped.

Answer (score 0):

If `instr({table.field},chr(10))=0` or `ubound(split({table.field},chr(10)))=1` then that character just doesn't exist in the string.

It might be worth mentioning, though, that `chr(10)` is a *line feed* and not a *carriage return* which is `chr(13)`. I suspect that you're just searching for the wrong character. Try it with `chr(13)` instead.

Comment: .@Ryan, I am sorry for that mistake and thanks for the answer. yes. chr(13) is a carriage return. But I don't have that on my database. Let's just say that I want to get the number of carriage return in a word wrapped field. But that's not possible I think. For there are no new line in a word wrapped field.

Comment: I think the wording here is part of the problem... if the string field is being wrapped by CR, that doesn't mean there is a carriage return or newline. Those are very specific characters that either exist within the string or don't. CR will wrap a field, yes, but it will not _add in_ a carriage return.

Comment: Yes. Thanks @Ryan for the answers. I knew for a fact that I will never get a carriage return on a wrapped field. I've done the requirement by using some formulas. Thanks guys. :)